# Why is the source IP not what I think it should be?

Tags: networking, routing, linux-networking

I noticed while setting up a VPN on my server that the source IP all packets going out is always the public IP of the server. But according to my understanding of my routing table, it should be the IP of the VPN. Also if I use `ping -I 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.42` it is again the public IP of my server.
What am I missing here?

This is the output of `tcpdump -n -i enp3s0 dst 213.225.3.191` while doing a ping with `ping -I 10.8.0.1 213.225.3.191`

```
17:34:36.285695 IP 5.9.142.112 > 213.225.3.191: ICMP echo request, id 10747, seq 34, length 64
```

This is the output of `tcpdump -n -i tun0` while doing a ping with `ping -I 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.42`

```
17:43:45.152792 IP 5.9.142.112 > 10.8.0.42: ICMP echo request, id 10834, seq 1, length 64
```

Output of `ip route`

```
default via 5.9.142.97 dev enp3s0 proto static 
5.9.142.97 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 5.9.142.112 
10.8.0.0/30 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 
10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
```

Output of `route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         static.97.142.9 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
static.97.142.9 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp3s0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.252 UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Output of `iptables -L -v -n -t nat`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 584K packets, 39M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    4   336 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp3s0  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp3s0  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
  285 18732 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            to:5.9.142.112
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp3s0  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      tun0    10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.8.0.42            to:10.8.0.1

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: It depends on how you configure both the routing and NAT on the VPN server. You can either preserve the IP address assigned by the VPN server to VPN clients or when that IP-address (range) is not routed (in either your own network, or the on the internet at large) then you must NAT that traffic to IP-address that IS routed. `iptables -L -v -n -t nat` or ìptables-save` might explain more

Comment: I added the output of it to question, I don't really know what to make of it

Comment: I think, based  on the packet counters , that your vpn traffic is matched by the rule `285 18732 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            to:5.9.142.112`

Answer (score 1):

To fully understand packet flow through Linux `iptables`, you will need [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) or something similar for reference. In the diagram, `ping` lives in the "local process" box in the application layer.

With your current routing table, the system wil "think" only traffic addressed to 10.8.0.0/24 will be routed to the VPN tunnel interface; everything else must go out via `enp3s0` without passing through the VPN tunnel.

When you run `ping -I 10.8.0.1 213.225.3.191`, the destination IP is not in the  10.8.0.0/24 block, and so `enp3s0` will be used. But the outbound route goes through gateway 5.9.142.97, and the route entry used to reach that gateway includes `src 5.9.142.112`, specifying the source address to be used.

And if that doesn't change the source IP, then the first MASQUERADE rule in the iptables postrouting table will.

```
4    336 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      enp3s0  10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0
```

The rule matches on all packets going out the `enp3s0` interface (as dictated by the routing decision) with the source IP in the 10.0.0.0/8 range, and 10.8.0.1 matches that range. And since it's a MASQUERADE rule, it changes the source IP address of the outgoing packet... to the IP address of the network interface the packet is going out of. First match wins, so this packet is done with the postrouting table and goes on to exit the system via `enp3s0`.

The result will exactly match what you see:

```
17:34:36.285695 IP 5.9.142.112 > 213.225.3.191: ICMP echo request, id 10747, seq 34, length 64
```

---

When you run `ping -I 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.42`, that is a valid destination for `tun0`, and the source address is valid for it too. Routing decision complete.

In the iptables/netfilter NAT postrouting table, the first two rules are restricted to match on traffic outgoing via `enp3s0`, so they won't apply. But then the outgoing packet hits this SNAT rule:

```
285 18732 SNAT       all  --  *      *       10.0.0.0/8           0.0.0.0/0            to:5.9.142.112
```

Any protocol, check. No interface specified in the rule, so it applies to `tun0`. Check. Source address within 10.0.0.0/8, check. Destination address anything, check. It's a match. This is a SNAT rule, so it modifies the **S**ource IP address. And it changes the source IP *to 5.9.142.112*. This may not be what you wanted, but this is what the rule says.

First match wins, so the packet is now done with the postrouting table: further entries will not be processed for this packet. And since the NAT postrouting table is the last table on the outgoing path, the packet will exit the system as it is now.

The result matches exactly this outgoing packet on `tun0`:

```
17:43:45.152792 IP 5.9.142.112 > 10.8.0.42: ICMP echo request, id 10834, seq 1, length 64
```

---

If you plan to pass all your internet traffic through the VPN, your routing table should have:

- a `5.9.142.97 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 5.9.142.112` route for your physical network interface. You already have this as it will be generated automatically when the physical network interface is configured.
- a /32 (or genmask 255.255.255.255) entry via your `enp3s0` gateway 5.9.142.97 to the public IP address of the remote endpoint of the VPN tunnel (which is not 10.8.0.2). This is to allow the VPN-encapsulated packets to go out through your real network interface and reach the remote VPN endpoint, even when you point your default gateway route through the VPN interface. Otherwise the outgoing VPN traffic will get re-encapsulated over and over again, creating a routing loop that prevents the VPN traffic actually getting to the remote VPN endpoint.
- an entry for the VPN tunnel itself: `10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1`. This will probably also get autogenerated when the `tun0` interface is configured.
- a default gateway entry via 10.8.0.2, pointing any traffic that has no more specific routing defined (i.e. basically everything that is not already VPN-encapsulated traffic going to the remote VPN endpoint) into the VPN tunnel.
- and nothing else. The default gateway entry will do the job of the `10.8.0.0/30 via 10.8.0.2` and `10.8.0.0/24 via 10.8.0.2` entries.

Unless your system is acting as a VPN gateway for other systems, you might not need any entries in the NAT POSTROUTING table at all.